# Hydroboration, steroselectivity and anti-markovnikov product

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, stereoselectivity, organoboron-compounds

My first question has to do with the fact that **Hydroboration produces an anti-markovnikov product, why?**. I don't see how that happens. A wikipedia artical says that B has a partial positive charge because it reacts slightly faster than H to form the bond but how is that possible when both H and C are more electronegative.

My second question is that **why are boranes, that are highly substituted, lead to a greater yield in anti-markovnikov product**?
Is it because something like 9-BBN can't be on top of a CH2 group because it's too big, and so it has to attach to the terminal C atom.

Comment: The regioselectivity of hydroboration is covered in practically every organic chemistry textbook. If Wikipedia's explanation doesn't suit you, then you should try a different source (Clayden is good). The reason is partly electronic (which is what Wikipedia was trying to explain: the C–B bond is formed slightly earlier than the C–H bond, so there's positive charge buildup on the *carbon to which the hydrogen will go*, and hence more substituted is better) and partly steric (which explains the second part).

Comment: The actual hydroboration step of an unsymmetrical alkene is a Markovnikov addition because boron is more electropositive than hydrogen. Alkaline peroxide oxidation of the borane exchanges boron bound to carbon for oxygen. Because electronegativity increases in the order B>H>O, it is this exchange process that makes the overall reaction anti-Markovnikov. In addition, the overall reaction is electroneutral in that the first step is a two-electron reduction while the second step is a two-electron oxidation.